# Typo3 footer repeat x

Tags: html, css, typo3, footer

I know there is a lot of threads on this, but none of those threads actually helped me.
I have a Typo3 based e-shop. I have footer which i want to be as wide, as my browser window. On my main page, there is no problem. But when I click on "Show all products", the list of products will appear but my footer is only 988px wide. In my index.html template file I have separated div for footer (it is not in any other div or block):
FOOTER

```
 <div id="footer">
    <div class="main-width">

        <div class="footer-menu" id="footerMenu">
           <a href="http://osc4.template-help.com/zencart_32899/">Home</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
           <a href="http://osc4.template-help.com/zencart_32899/index.php?main_page=products_new">New Products</a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
           <a href="http://osc4.template-help.com/zencart_32899/index.php?main_page=specials">Specials</a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
           <a href="http://osc4.template-help.com/zencart_32899/index.php?main_page=products_all">Products All</a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
           <a href="http://osc4.template-help.com/zencart_32899/index.php?main_page=reviews">Reviews</a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
           <a href="http://osc4.template-help.com/zencart_32899/index.php?main_page=contact_us">Contact Us</a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
           <a href="http://osc4.template-help.com/zencart_32899/index.php?main_page=gv_faq">FAQ</a> 
 </div>
 <div class="copyright">
           Copyright &copy; 2013 
          </div>
                </div>

           </div>
```

When I load my page in OPERA and click (in opera) on "Inspect element" It seems like my footer (on all products page) is in some kind of div (contentWrapper):

```
 <body id="indexBody">
     - <div class="main-width">
         + <div id="header">
           <div class="banners"/>
         + <div class="crsl">
         - <div id="contentWrapper">
            + <div id="sidebar">
            + <div id="content_container">
            + <div id="footer">

 </div>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

The + and - shows which divs are collapsed and which are not. Hope Its clear. :)
On my main page, when I click inspect element, my footer isnt inside of that "contentWrapper" div. Where could be problem? Please Help

Comment: A hyperlink would be useful so we can inspect for ourselves

Comment: I have it on my localhost, so that could be difficult :(

Comment: Then it's going to be hard...do the main page and the product page use different templates? I'm not familiar with Typo3

Comment: No. I have products_template.html, where is defined how products should be organized and on my main page I also have list of products. All of this happened when I was trying to format list of products. I had to put that product box(Category_title,product_title,product_image,buy_button) in one div, so every new category of products starts on new line. Here is style of that div: {display: inline-block; float:left; }

Comment: As I said, unless we can see the pages in action it's hard to help.

Answer (score 0):

Never trust those element inspectors since they always display an interpreted source code in a fancy collapsible tree view. Have a look at the plain source code and count the div tags. I bet the second template misses a closing one ;-)

Comment: I have checked it. No closing tag is missing. I even tried to put one there, but it was worse. I seriously dont know what should be my problem.